# IIS 7: using IP address and port for different sites

Tags: iis, iis-7, firewall, port

I have an IIS7 set up. So far I do not have a domain name for it however we have an IP address.

I want to have just two environments on this server, one for staging and one for production.

Staging - being the area of client testing / area that is pre production, and 
production - The final product.

I have been successful so far in creating a binding to port 80 for production(ie the default website) and a binding for staging on 8081.

The production works on localhost and remotely too however the staging(8081) will only work on local host.

I have opened the port 8081 in Windows firewall, but still am unable to access this site from a remote location. Specifically the error i am getting is:

```
**Oops! This link appears to be broken.**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides your Windows Server firewall, is there **another firewall** (or router) device protecting that server? Did you forget to open and/or forward that port to the server?

Answer (score 1):

Double check your web browser isn't configured to use a proxy server...  Worst case you could run WireShark on the web server and see if the web requests are actually making it to the web server on that port (8081)...

Also, run the command line tool "netstat -na" and see if there is an entry for the 8081 binding.  Something like:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Comment: yeah ran that a while back and yes it was turned on. There was an external hardware firewall which i did not know about. argh. Thanks very much for your help.